# Relay chain argument error: Invalid input: Error parsing spec file: unknown field `relay_chain` at line 75 column 1

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator

I Need to `Connect to Local Parachain` .

I did step by step every thing in this page : [Substrate](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-parachain/)

in section `Start a collator node` i run this command :

```
./target/release/parachain-collator \
--alice \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain <relay chain raw chain spec> \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977
```

in this section `--chain <relay chain raw chain spec> \` i used `rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json` but i got this error :

> 2022-07-11 20:02:31 ⛓  Native runtime: template-parachain-1 (template-parachain-0.tx1.au1)
> Error: Input("Relay chain argument error: Invalid input: Error parsing spec file: unknown field `relay_chain` at line 75 column 1")

**what's the problem? how can i solve this error ???**

Comment: Provide your chain spec file? It likely is a simple error that could not parse. Perhaps try an ide with error detection for json formatting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the `relay chain` spec in `--chain <relay chain raw chain spec> \`, for example the one created for `rococo-local` with the command

```bash
polkadot build-spec --chain rococo-local --disable-default-bootnode --raw > rococo-local.json
```

Thanks!

Comment: I Faced this Error :  `zsh: command not found: polkadot`

Comment: You need to first complete this tutorial (https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-relay/), where you clone and build `polkadot`.